# Bash script part data in row with regex

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Let say I have file test.txt and it look like this:

```
14.03.2016  12:01:58    0001039 28,427    0,200     28,427  28,437  28,427
14.03.2016  12:02:28    0001090 28,442    0,200     28,442  28,439  28,444
14.03.2016  12:02:58    0001139 28,469    0,230     28,459  28,469  28,504
```

I need to parse this with bash script so that I get for each row:

```
a = 14.03.2016
b = 12:01:58
c = 0001039
d = 0,200
```

I am not sure how to do this with grep.

Comment: Are `a,b,c,d` shell variables?

Comment: yes they need to be :D

Comment: see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash has this pretty much built in.

```
while read -r a b c _ d rest; do
    : things with "$a", "$b", "$c", and "$d"
done <inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

AWK to the rescue

```
cat myscript.awk
BEGIN { RS = "\n" ; FS = " " }

{
      print "a = ", $1
      print "b = ", $2
      print "c = ", $3
      print "d = ", $5
}

awk -f myscript.awk inputfile

a =  14.03.2016
b =  12:01:58
c =  0001039
d =  0,200
a =  14.03.2016
b =  12:02:28
c =  0001090
d =  0,200
a =  14.03.2016
b =  12:02:58
c =  0001139
d =  0,230
```

Comment: What's with the `RS` and `FS` assignments? The defaults should be fine.

Comment: True. If the OP wants to change record separator and field separator for some reason he must know where to change. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first line of your input file is stored in variable `line`, you can do

```
arr=($line)
```

to make an array consisting of the individual words in the line.

```
a=${arr[0]}
```

would then assign the first word to variable a.

Answer (score 0):

Another way if the name a,b,... are not required.

```
while read line;do
  set -- $line
  echo '$3 = '"$3"' $6 = '"$6"
done< infile
```